# Github is not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-actions

I have tried to install the GitHub pull and request extensions in the Visual Studio Code.I installed it. But when I searched "Github" in the Visual Studio there is nothing showing in the visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I will try to answer it based on my understanding.

Try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search git, you should see all git commands.

From [the official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github):

> To get started with the GitHub in VS Code, you'll need to install Git, create a GitHub account and install the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension.
> Once you've installed the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension, you'll need to sign in.

After this, you can search for and clone a repository from GitHub using the *Git: Clone* command in the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) or by using the *Clone Repository* button in the Source Control view (available when you have no folder open).